# Customize position for certain node in d3 org chart

Tags: d3.js, d3-org-chart

How to customize position of certain node in d3 org chart? You can use [layout bindings](https://github.com/bumbeishvili/org-chart/blob/0b70fef70f801855e335f7db061237491eaa31fd/src/d3-org-chart.js#L293) such as `nodeUpdateTransform` to modify each node. But the node is just a parameter-object with no identifier `{ x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100 }`. For example, how to  identify the "node2" in the code snippet below to modify x value?

```js
const data = [
    { customId: 1, customParentId: null, customName: 'node1' },
    { customId: 2, customParentId: 1, customName: 'node2' },
    { customId: 3, customParentId: 1, customName: 'node3' },
  ];

    chart = new d3.OrgChart()
      .nodeId((dataItem) => dataItem.customId)
      .parentNodeId((dataItem) => dataItem.customParentId)
      .nodeWidth((node) => 100)
      .nodeHeight((node) => 100)
      .nodeContent((node) => {
        return `<div customId="${node.data.customId}" 
            style="background-color:aqua;width:${node.width}px;height:${node.height}px"
          > 
               ${node.data.customName}
           </div>`;
      })
      .container('.chart-container')
      .data(data).render();

   const layout = chart.layoutBindings();
   layout.top.nodeUpdateTransform = node => `translate(${(node.x-100) - node.width / 2},${node.y})`;
    chart.layoutBindings(layout).render();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-org-chart@3.0.1"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-flextree@2.1.2/build/d3-flextree.js"></script>

<div class="chart-container"></div>
```

I can think about two approaches:

1. Modify the element after DOM is generated (`d3.select('[customId="2"]');`). But then you have to modify position each time, when the chart is `.onExpandOrCollapse`.
2. Count through the tree. But disadvantage of this approach is, if the amount of nodes changes, the index could be change.

   ```
    i=0;
    layout.top.nodeUpdateTransform = function(node){
      if(i==1){
        i+=1;
        return `translate(${(node.x-100) - node.width / 2},${node.y})`;
      }
      i+=1;
      return `translate(${(node.x) - node.width / 2},${node.y})`;
    }
   ```

Comment: When I answered your last question I also thought about this problem.  I couldn't come up with a good solution.  You could always modify the `d3-org-chart` source code to also pass `d` as an argument [here](https://github.com/bumbeishvili/org-chart/blob/0b70fef70f801855e335f7db061237491eaa31fd/src/d3-org-chart.js#L1148).